# Trying to decode a JWT token, however decode function returning unexpected Object and attributes are not accessible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, jwt

thank you in advance for the help. I am currently attempting to decode a JWT token on my frontend react app sent from a ruby on rails restful API. I am creating the token on the back end like so:

```
def create

    @user = User.find_by(email: session_params[:email])

    if @user && @user.authenticate(session_params[:password])

        token = JWT.encode(@user, ENV["JWT_SECRET"])


        render json: {
            email: @user.email, 
            name: @user.name, 
            discipline: @user.discipline,
            id: @user.id,
            token: token
        } 
    else
        render json:{
            error: "User not Found",
            details: @user.errors.full_messages
        }, status: :unauthorized
    end
end
```

I then handle saving it to local storage on the front end, and then attempting to decode the token like this:

````
export function checkLoginStatus() {
  let token = window.localStorage.getItem("ST_APP");
  if (token) {
    let user = decode(token);
    console.log(user);
    return user; //returns user object
  } else {
    return false; //returns false if ST_APP token not found in local storage
  }
}```

The problem is that console.log(user) prints #<User:0x00007f3870068ec0> and the attributes of the object are innaccessible. From all the documentation I have been looking at I would expect decode(token) to return a plain old javascript object that I could then access the attributes of. This is my first time working with JWT tokens so any advice is appreciated.
````

Comment: I don't know how ruby prints objects as a string but I've never seen an object printed like the one in your example (`<User:0x00007f3870068ec0>`) in javascript. This leads me to think that somewhere along the process that JSON you render in your `create` function does not serialize appropiately. Have you tested the auth endpoint with something like postman to see that it returns actual JSON? `<User:0x00007f3870068ec0>` looks like an object with a memory reference though im not sure.

Comment: This is 100% correct. I was able to correct the problem by instead of encoding the token like ```JWT.encode(@user, ENV["JWT_SECRET"])``` and was able to fix the problem by encoding the token like this: ```JWT.encode({email: @user.email, name: @user.name, etc...}, ENV["JWT_SECRET"]) ```